# Can we use [remote] attribute in ASP.NET Core Web API implementation?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I wanted to do server-side validation for my APIs getting consumed in a vue js frontend application. I tried putting `[remote]` attribute on my model class fields to check if given input does not exist already. ex, username, email.

`User.cs`:

```
public class User
{
    [Remote(action: "VerifyUsername", controller:"Validation")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

`ValidationController`:

```
[HttpGet("VerifyUsername")]
public JsonResult VerifyUsername(string Username)
{
    if (_userService.VerifyUsername(Username))
    {
        return Json($"User {Username} is already in use.");
    }

    return Json(true);
}
```

`UsersController`:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateUser([FromBody]User user)
{
    return Accepted(_userService.CreateUser(user));
}
```

When I test the above sample code with swagger

API `POST /Users`

Post body:

```
{
    Username: "adminuser"
}
```

The user gets created even though user `adminuser` already exists in the backend.

I am not sure what am I missing here, or is it that `[remote]` attribute only works in ASP.NET Core Razor pages ?

Answer (score 0):

[Remote validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#remote-attribute) works hand in hand with jQuery Validation. It merely emits some HTML attributes. So, for forms where you have jQuery Validation loaded. It prevents POSTing invalid forms, it's no substitute for serverside validation.

So if you want this validation in an API (`UserController.CreateUser()`), you'll have to reimplement it there.

Comment: by reimplementing you mean write validation code inside the controller rather than using [remote] attribute ? because i want to test the attribute from swagger if possible

Comment: Yes, in the controller. The attribute does not validate, it tells Razor to emit jQuery Validation data attributes which tell jQuery how to validate an input field.